# Showing there is an inductive set that contains no limit ordinals

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

If we define a ***natural number*** $n$ as
$$n\in\bigcap\{x:x\text{ is an inductive set}\}$$
then showing any natural number is either zero or a successor ordinal is equivalent to showing there is an inductive set containing no limit ordinals. How can this be shown?

It's clear that *some* successor ordinals exist: $\{\emptyset\}$; and that an inductive *class* with no limit ordinals also exists:
$$\emptyset\cup\{\alpha: \alpha \text{ is a successor ordinal}\},$$

yet I still struggle to prove the result.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand your definition from a technical point of view, the collection of all inductive sets doesn't form a set, so we cannot take its intersection, furthermore, even if it were a set, this intersection will be empty, as there are many non-equal but isomorphic inductive sets, usually this might be ignored, but to me it seems rather important as this is a purely set theoretical question

Comment: @Carlye You can take an intersection of a proper class, since by the axiom schema of specification, if $\phi$ is the formula describing the class, you can take any single member $X$ of the class and then the intersection is equal to $\{x\in X\mid \forall Y (\phi(Y)\implies x\in Y)\}$.  Taking a **union** of a proper class would be problematic, but intersections are fine.  Also, I believe we are using the definition given in my answer below, so there is no concept of isomorphism at play.  In other words, all inductive sets must include $\emptyset$, $s(\emptyset)$, $s(s(\emptyset))$, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are defining an inductive set as one that contains $\emptyset$ and contains $s(\alpha):=\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$ whenever it contains $\alpha$, you can reason as follows:

By the axiom of infinity, there is some inductive set $X$.  Let $$Y=\{\alpha\in X\mid \alpha \text{ is empty or is a successor ordinal.}\}.$$  Then $\emptyset\in Y$, and if $\alpha\in Y$, then $s(\alpha)$ is a successor ordinal (since $\alpha$ is an ordinal) in $X$ (since $X$ is inductive), and so is also in $Y$, so $Y$ is inductive, and by definition $Y$ consists only of $\emptyset$ and successor ordinals.

Then in conclusion, as you observed in your question, the minimal inductive set $\mathbb N$ is contained in $Y$, hence also consists only of $\emptyset$ and successor ordinals.

Answer (score 0):

We'll show $$\bigcap\{x:x\text{ is a limit ordinal}\}$$ is an inductive set containing no limit ordinal. Since there is a limit ordinal, this is a set. If $$y\in \bigcap\{x:x\text{ is a limit ordinal}\},$$ then for each limit ordinal $x$, $y\in x$, hence $y\neq x$. This shows the set contains no limit ordinals. Clearly $$0\in \bigcap\{x:x\text{ is a limit ordinal}\}.$$ If $$y\in \bigcap\{x:x\text{ is a limit ordinal}\},$$ then for any limit ordinal $x$, $y\in x$, hence $y+1\in x$, and $$y+1\in \bigcap\{x:x\text{ is a limit ordinal}\}.$$